# Make feh (image viewer similar to xv) readonly?

Tags: read-only, image-processing, image-editor

I used feh (an image viewer similar to xv) to view an image and then keyboard ">" to view the image rotated and then "q" to quit. feh *overwrote the original image with the rotated image*!

How do I tell feh I only want to view my images rotated, not save them that way?

In other words, I want feh to behave more like xv, and not overwrite (or save) images without my explicit say-so. I do like feh's other features (like captioning and it's better resizing capabilities), so using xv instead is not a solution.

I realize I could make the images read-only in the filesystem, but that seems extreme. Surely feh has a "read only" option?

I did look at `man feh` and found nothing.

**EDIT**: following @A.B.'s excellent suggestion, I found a super hacky way to disable feh's "in place editing" by tweaking the source of `imlib.c`. Simply add this line:

```
FEH_FILE(w->file->data)->filename = "/tmp/fehhack";
```

after this one (all in `void feh_edit_inplace(winwidget w, int op)`):

```
if (!w->file || !w->file->data || !FEH_FILE(w->file->data)->filename)
    return;
```

The rotated image will now be stored in and reloaded from the file `/tmp/fehhack`. Not happy with this "solution", but it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design. The menu entry is <kbd>File</kbd> (**!)** and the menu entry for rotate is <kbd>Edit in Place</kbd> (**!!!**).

You have two options:

1. Write a change request, the package is maintained [here](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-phototools/feh.git/)
2. Clone the repository, write a patch and create a pull request.

   I think, you have to change the function `feh_edit_inplace(winwidget w, int op)` in `imlib.c`

   ```
   void feh_edit_inplace(winwidget w, int op)
   {
           int ret;
           Imlib_Image old;
           Imlib_Load_Error err;
           if (!w->file || !w->file->data || !FEH_FILE(w->file->data)->filename)
                   return;

           if (!strcmp(gib_imlib_image_format(w->im), "jpeg")) {
                   feh_edit_inplace_lossless(w, op);
                   feh_reload_image(w, 1, 1);
                   return;
           }

           ret = feh_load_image(&old, FEH_FILE(w->file->data));
           if (ret) {
                   if (op == INPLACE_EDIT_FLIP) {
                           imlib_context_set_image(old);
                           imlib_image_flip_vertical();
                   } else if (op == INPLACE_EDIT_MIRROR) {
                           imlib_context_set_image(old);
                           imlib_image_flip_horizontal();
                   } else
                           gib_imlib_image_orientate(old, op);
                   gib_imlib_save_image_with_error_return(old,
                           FEH_FILE(w->file->data)->filename, &err);
                   gib_imlib_free_image(old);
                   if (err)
                           feh_imlib_print_load_error(FEH_FILE(w->file->data)->filename,
                                   w, err);
                   feh_reload_image(w, 1, 1);
           } else {
                   im_weprintf(w, "failed to load image from disk to edit it in place");
           }

           return;
   }
   ```

Comment: I feel silly. I looked at the manual page again and it does mention "In place editing" and "orient_3" and "orient_1". Perhaps there's a keybinding for "rotate without editing" but haven't found it yet.